# Show Newest File Added To Website Directory While Excluding Some Specific Files in PHP

Tags: php

Found this code online that was very helpful. I have been trying to tweak it for a few hours now to exclude a certain file name of (mobile.htm). Can I get some help in the right direction to exclude the mobile.htm file name before the result is displayed and how can i display the full path to the file so I can turn it into a link?

```
<?php
$path = "states"; 
$latest_ctime = 0;
$latest_filename = '';    
$d = dir($path);
while (false !== ($entry = $d->read())) {
   $filepath = "{$path}/{$entry}";
   if(is_file($filepath) && filectime($filepath) > $latest_ctime) {
      $latest_ctime = filectime($filepath);
      $latest_filename = $entry;
      echo $latest_filename;
?>
```

**UPDATE: This is the code I got to work for me. I had $var that I was trying to view on an index page that wasnt being seen. What worked for me was making a iframe on the homepage that linked to another page that carried the $_SESSION info of the $var. Here is the code that i placed int he iframe that worked for me.**

The 3 **if ($entry == "YourFile.html") {continue;}** that I have listed stop the request from showing specific files you enter.

```
<?php
$path = "states/$ls"; 
$latest_ctime = 0;
$latest_filename = '';
$d = dir($path);
while ($entry = $d->read()) {
if ($entry == "mobile.htm") {continue;}
if ($entry == "bg.jpg") {continue;}
if ($entry == "flag.png") {continue;}
$filepath = "$path/$entry";
$ctime = filectime($filepath);
if (is_file($filepath) && $ctime > $latest_ctime) {
    $latest_ctime = $ctime;
    $latest_filename = $filepath;
}
}
echo $latest_filename;
?>
```

A huge thank you to @Barmar below for helping me. I absolutely love this website and community.

Comment: just add a `&& $entry != 'mobile.html'` to the if clause

Comment: @Jeff I tried and its still showing the result of mobile.htm.

Comment: [pathinfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) is your friend here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `continue;` statement to skip to the next iteration of the loop.

```
while ($entry = $d->read()) {
    if ($entry == "mobile.html") {
        continue;
    }
    $filepath = "$path/$entry";
    $ctime = filectime($filepath);
    if (is_file($filepath) && $ctime > $latest_ctime) {
        $latest_ctime = $ctime;
        $latest_filename = $filepath;
    }
}
echo $latest_filename;
```

I put `$filepath` in `$latest_filename` since you want the full path for your link.

Comment: You know, I went back to edit the code and its no longer working, with or without your code. Nothing has changed, but the code just isnt working anymore... Would you be able to help me write a code to replace what i originally posted or at least help me in the right direction?

Comment: Never mind I got it working. Small change in a capitalized letter was causing the issue.  Thank you so much @Barmar

Comment: I updated my original post with your answer. I hope this helps others in the future. Thank you so much.

Comment: You should put the solution you used in an Answer, not the question.